# how to block access in asp.net for url of other folders?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Asp.net web application in which I have two folders Folder1 and Folder2 with some aspx files.Both folders have own login page in which the users are same. Now I want that when login in Folder1 login.aspx and access some files of Folder2 then I should be able to access them directly instead the login.aspx of Folder2 should be displayed.

Comment: It depends how you configured your site. If it's ONE site then this behavior is not default one and you have some code to enforce it

Comment: Simply maintain a session (or more perfect way to use Form Authentication and maintain Auth Cookie) on successful log in from login page and check if session already exists (while accessing Folder2) then allow them direct access.

Comment: Each folder can have it's own web.config file which specifies allow and deny for roles, users, anonymous and authorized.  This tool may help you achieve your goal.

Comment: yeah now I am done with it.. Just have to do deny the users to access the particular url's.